# Asignar un valor a un puntero int en c

Tags: c++, c

Intento asignar el valor de una variable del tipo int a un puntero del mismo tipo, tiene 9 posiciones, y le quiero asignar un valor en la posicion 1, pero si imprimo el valor en el scope de la funcion muestra el valor(10), pero al ver el valor fuera de la funcion me dice que es 0.

```
void showMenu(){
    int cantPerType[9] = {0} ;
    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            setPlayerByRole(...,cantPerType);
            printf("Valor: %d ",cantPerType[1]);//0
            break;
    }
}

void setPlayerByRole(...,int *cantPerType){
    cantPerType[1] = 10;
    printf("cant 2: %d ",cantPerType[1]); // 10
    showMenu();
}
```

Comment: C++ o C? Son lenguajes diferentes. Por cierto, no llames a `showMenu` desde `setPlayerByRole` porque no permites que la función `showMenu` finalice. Por consiguiente la memoria del stack no puede liberarse. Mejor pon un `while(true) showMenu();` en la función `main` o donde sea que lo llames inicialmente.

Answer (score 1):

Los arrays se pasan directamente por referencia, por lo que no es necesario que uses *.

Se haría de la siguiente forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//PROTOTIPOS
void setPlayerByRole(int cantPerType[]);



void showMenu(){
    int cantPerType[9] = {0} ;
    int option = 1; //establecemos opcion a 1 para las pruebas

    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            setPlayerByRole(cantPerType);
            printf("Valor: %d ",cantPerType[1]);//0
            break;
    }
}

void setPlayerByRole(int cantPerType[]){
    cantPerType[1] = 10;
    printf("cant 2: %d ",cantPerType[1]); // 10
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    showMenu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Intente de la forma que comentas, pero aun sigue sin funcionar. Gracias de igual forma